# Как устроены структуры Python такие как list, tuple, deque под капотом

Tags: python, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Насколько я уже знаю, list и tuple это указатели на массив ссылок которые в свою очередь ссылаются на объекты в куче. Но при этом поиск в кортеже быстрее (не совсем понятно почему, таже арифметика указателей) ну и весит он меньше. Что касается deque, то я знаком с тем как она реализована в том же С++ (куча связанных массивов между собой с возможностью более быстрого поиска и средней скорости добавления). Но как она реализована в Python? Я проверял размер пустой deque она весит 624 бита, но хотелось бы узнать в чем особенность и преимущества этих 3-х структур между собой

Comment: А что помешало спросить то же самое в поисковике? я всегда считал что люди которые готовы воспринять материал такого уровня - могут использовать гугл и яндекс... https://alex-podrabinovich.medium.com/под-капотом-python-объекты-и-типы-9bc883b5637a ... первая строка яндекса по запросу "Питон типы под капотом"

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, не натыкался на эту статью

Comment: Статья интересная, но реализуцию данных структур так и не нашел еще

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/273045/ уф... я то думал.... 2 https://habr.com/ru/post/417783/.. дочитаете - обращайтесь, погуглю за вас

Comment: Да я что-то совсем обленился)), спасибо за инфу,  преисполнился немного